# How to cropped thumbnail image without distorting it?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have post thumbnail image size: `852x421`:

I follow the document here: `https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size` to crop the picture to my liking, but it not working

From the post thumbnail image I want to crop the image to `362x421`, same height and smaller width

My image:[image]

Comment: Are you asking about images which were uploaded before changes were made?

Comment: Yes, i want to show image cropped on Blog List page